# SignalR sends two messages to client when page refreshed

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Using SignalR and sending a message to all clients from a Controller

```
hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("parsestatus", new ParseStatus() { message = message, clientid = clientid });
```

My client code:

```
hubConnection.on("parsestatus", message => {
    console.log(message);
});
```

The first time I load the page, I get one message. If I refresh, I get two messages. Refresh again, I get three messages.

the SignalR Hub is obviously holding on to the old connections and adding a new connection when the page is refreshed. I assumed it would release the connection when the page was reloaded.

Is there any way to make SignalR drop the previous connection when a page is reloaded?